# Why strips occur when simulating smoke with collision?

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

I wonder why those strips occur when simulating smokes with collision. increasing Domain division will impove it some, but will not completely remove that kind of thing. How to get rid of them?

[image]

[image]

Example file is [here](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/32215). Thanks for any help.

### EDIT:

For anyone being interested in solving this, please see comment below from Lukas, which explains everything.

Comment: I think this is a inherent limitation  of the smoke simulator, you'll notice that the liquid simulator does this too.. :/ I'm guessing this kind of problem isn't present in SPH simulators, hopefully blender's SPH system will get some features soon ;)

Comment: This was partially a bug, see https://developer.blender.org/T43674. Now you shouldn't get any more leakage and density stepping.
It is true though that some aliasing is inherent to grid simulations like smoke or fluids. Best way to avoid is to subdiv+displace the collider a bit and avoid large flat surfaces.